# Javascript function inside loop

Tags: javascript

Any one have any idea why this doesn't work as expected? Just fires alerts on page load.

```
var div = document.querySelectorAll('.div'); // NodeList of all instances of '.div'

var eventFunction = function() {
  alert('ggdf');
};


for(var i = 0; i < div.length; i++) { // Begin '.div' NodeList loop

  div[i].addEventListener('click', eventFunction(), false); // Click function on all instances of '.div'

} // End '.div' NodeList loop
```

Answer (score 5):

Your executing the function when passing it to the `eventListener` function, instead use:

```
for(var i = 0; i < div.length; i++) {  
  div[i].addEventListener('click', eventFunction, false); //notice no ()
}
```

Functions can be passed as arguments the same way as other variables, but when you pass them with `()` after them your invoking the function and the object/value returned by the function is passed as the argument.

Also unless you have added a class `div` to all your divs I think you want to use a tag selector:

```
var div = document.querySelectorAll('div');
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/rG3AC/1/

Comment: Ahh right I see, thanks for this, just getting to grips with library-less JS, coming from a PHP background little things keep tripping me up, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the function so that it doesn't trigger immediately.

```
div[i].addEventListener('click', eventFunction.bind(), false);
```

Comment: Does not point out the acutal mistake - cant see how this one helps at all here.